# how to get weekly data from Google Analytics account using RGA package based on local date settings

Tags: r, google-analytics

Trying to get data from a Google Analytics account using the (sample) code below. I want the results grouped by weekly; for this reason added **ga:week** as the last dimension.

```
ga_data <- get_ga(id, start.date = "2017-02-27", end.date = "2017-03-05",
                  metrics = "ga:bounceRate, ga:sessions,
                  dimensions = "ga:Medium, ga:week",
                  segment = "gaid::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  include.empty.rows = "TRUE")
```

In this way, it accepts Sunday as the first day of the week; however I want it to start with Monday (as in my local settings).

I have 3 questions:

1) Is it possible to edit this using a parameter within the package ("RGA")?

2) If it is not possible, how can I group it weekly manually?

3) What is exactly the argument `fetch.by` in `get_ga()` function? (In the documentation it says *"character. Split the query by date range. Allowed values: "day", "week", "month", "quarter", "year"*.)

Let me know if any additional info needed.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: regarding to the comment from @ArtemKlevtsov

When I add *date* as a new dimension it becomes below daily format; then all the metrics I added (there are more metrics in original code) need to be aggregated manually using the column *"weekDesired"* with additional coding. Am I right? I can do this; but just wanted to be sure there is no easier way with less coding.

```
> ga_data  <- get_ga(id, start.date = "2017-02-26", end.date = "2017-03-06",
+                                metrics = "ga:bounceRate, ga:sessions",
+                                dimensions = "ga:Medium, ga:week, ga:date",
+                                segment = "gaid::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
+                                include.empty.rows = "TRUE")

> library(lubridate)
> ga_data$weekDay <- wday(ga_data$date, label = T)
> ga_data$weekDesired <- format(ga_data$date, "%W")
> head(ga_data,16)

   Medium  week       date bounceRate sessions weekDay weekDesired
    <chr> <chr>     <dttm>      <dbl>    <int>   <ord>       <chr>
1  (none)    09 2017-02-26   66.66667        3     Sun          08
2  (none)    09 2017-02-27   50.00000        6     Mon          09
3  (none)    09 2017-02-28   80.00000        5    Tues          09
4  (none)    09 2017-03-01   20.00000        5     Wed          09
5  (none)    09 2017-03-02   57.14286       14   Thurs          09
6  (none)    09 2017-03-03   75.00000        8     Fri          09
7  (none)    09 2017-03-04  100.00000        4     Sat          09
8  (none)    10 2017-03-05  100.00000        4     Sun          09
9  (none)    10 2017-03-06   38.46154       13     Mon          10
10 banner    09 2017-02-26   22.22222        9     Sun          08
11 banner    09 2017-02-27   36.84211       19     Mon          09
12 banner    09 2017-02-28   58.33333       12    Tues          09
13 banner    09 2017-03-01   53.33333       15     Wed          09
14 banner    09 2017-03-02   50.00000       12   Thurs          09
15 banner    09 2017-03-03   54.54545       11     Fri          09
16 banner    09 2017-03-04   25.00000       12     Sat          09
```

Comment: Add `ga:date` to dimensions.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov, thanks for replying. I've just made some edits in the question regarding to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ga:isoYearIsoWeek` instead of `ga:week` as a dimension solved the problem. Now when I remove the `ga:date` it will be weekly basis (starting from Monday).

For those having similar issues below link may help:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_isoyearisoweek

```
> ga_data  <- get_ga(id, start.date = "2017-02-26", end.date = "2017-03-06",
+                    metrics = "ga:bounceRate, ga:sessions",
+                    dimensions = "ga:Medium, ga:isoYearIsoWeek, ga:date",
+                    segment = "gaid::4SZBNy34Taypmuk_Mczdow",
+                    include.empty.rows = "TRUE")

> ga_data$weekDay <- wday(ga_data$date, label = T)
> ga_data$weekDesired <- format(ga_data$date, "%W")
> head(ga_data,20)

   Medium **isoYearIsoWeek**       date bounceRate sessions weekDay **weekDesired**
    <chr>          <chr>     <dttm>      <dbl>    <int>   <ord>       <chr>
1  (none)         201708 2017-02-26   66.66667        3     Sun          08
2  (none)         201709 2017-02-27   50.00000        6     Mon          09
3  (none)         201709 2017-02-28   80.00000        5    Tues          09
4  (none)         201709 2017-03-01   20.00000        5     Wed          09
5  (none)         201709 2017-03-02   57.14286       14   Thurs          09
6  (none)         201709 2017-03-03   75.00000        8     Fri          09
7  (none)         201709 2017-03-04  100.00000        4     Sat          09
8  (none)         201709 2017-03-05  100.00000        4     Sun          09
9  (none)         201710 2017-03-06   38.46154       13     Mon          10
10 banner         201708 2017-02-26   22.22222        9     Sun          08
11 banner         201709 2017-02-27   36.84211       19     Mon          09
12 banner         201709 2017-02-28   58.33333       12    Tues          09
13 banner         201709 2017-03-01   53.33333       15     Wed          09
14 banner         201709 2017-03-02   50.00000       12   Thurs          09
15 banner         201709 2017-03-03   54.54545       11     Fri          09
16 banner         201709 2017-03-04   25.00000       12     Sat          09
17 banner         201709 2017-03-05   27.27273       11     Sun          09
18 banner         201710 2017-03-06   44.44444       18     Mon          10
19    cpc         201708 2017-02-26   52.15239     4646     Sun          08
20    cpc         201709 2017-02-27   52.73286     4885     Mon          09
```

Comment: You set ga:isoYearIsoWeek but for the date range, the range is still in USA weeks standard (Sunday first day, Saturday last day), is it really correct or should we prepare the date range according to the ga:isoYearIsoWeek?